# The VBA documentation is poorly structured

Tags: vba, documentation

How to understand the VBA documentation? The documentation is poorly structured. For example, there are various libraries such as Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library. But if you look for information about the contents of these libraries by their name, you will not find single (or main) pages of these libraries. The data is scattered and there is not a single page with content titles to the required libraries. If I'm right in this aspect, then it's terrible. I have experience programming in Python in terms of data analysis and there the information is clearly structured by libraries (the main thing is to know the name of the required libraries). Hence several questions.

1) What is the most effective way to find the necessary VBA documentation for specific libraries?

2) Am I right that the VBA documentation is poorly structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a useful exploring method for you.

In the VBE you will be able to access the object model via the  Object Browser Icon (or press <kbd>F2</kbd>)

Then type it what you are interested in, or browse through the options available.

Select an item and press <kbd>F1</kbd> to call up the help file.

Example:

[image: Getting info]